# Error 1004 "Excel can't navigate to the desired location..." Durring copy

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to copy a single sheet to a new workbook and keep getting the following error when I execute the copy: [image]

I don't know if this makes a difference or not but the sheet I am trying to copy was created by a VBA macro earlier in the process.

Here is my code:

````
    Dim FName As String
    Dim FPath As String

    FPath = "/Users/phild/Dropbox (SGPS ShowRig)/DDocuments/ARCHIVES/Z_Last Weeks Accounts Archives"
    FName = "New Workbook" & ".xlsx"

    Debug.Print "WB = " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Debug.Print "WS = " & ActiveSheet.Name
    
    Worksheets("ZLastWeekOnly").Copy

    If Dir(FPath & "/" & FName) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File " & FPath & "/" & FName & " already exists"
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FPath & "/" & FName
    End If

End Sub```
````

Comment: I see a typo in DDocuments, is that the intended path?

Comment: Yes "DDocuments: is correct. Thanx though

Comment: Could be something similar to windows: when the path name is too long may give this errors, can you try in a shorter path? Also the spaces may be something that is messing up the path location too, try to use underscores if possible

Comment: I want to add that at the time of the error the Activesheet is the sheet that I want to copy.

Comment: So, does ActiveSheet.Copy work?